# I am trying to iterate the foreach data and print in li format in the textarea field.below is my code

Tags: php, html

in my output, li and ul are also printed, but I only want task data, not in one line of textarea.

```
<input type="teaxtarea" name="task" class="form-control task" value="
<ol>
<?php foreach($val['task'] as $task) { ?>
<li><?php echo $task; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ol>">
```

Comment: A textarea will only have plaintext, not formatted code, so it will print the li and ol.

Comment: Look at the HTML reference. A TEXTAREA does not have a `value` attribute, nor is it an input element

Comment: `<textarea...> Data goes here </textarea>`

Comment: `textarea` is not a type of `input`. It's a tag `<textarea>`

Comment: Always read the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea and look at examples (which are plentiful there and in many other places)

Comment: Thanks, guys, but would you let me know if i want to show the data in li format in which I can edit the data also So what is the possible solution?

Comment: It sounds like you would need a rich text editor which runs in a browser and supports HTML editing. Maybe take a look at ckeditor or a similar tool

Answer (score 1):

Use a contenteditable div. It's a lazy solution that has its shortcomings.

```js
var editor = document.querySelector(".my-editor")

function save() {
  console.log(editor.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-editor" contenteditable style="border: 1px solid gray">
  <ol>
    <li>My task 1 (edit me)</li>
    <li>My task 2</li>
    <li>My task 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<button onclick="save()">save</button>
```